# Rails content_tag inserts extra "<" and ">" characters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When doing this:

```
def user_log
    if logged_in? == false
        form_tag session_path, :id => "mform" do
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(text_field_tag :email, "email@domain.com"), :class => "memail")+
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(password_field_tag :password, "12345678912"), :class => "mpass")+
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(submit_tag 'Login'), :class => "mbutton")
        end
    else
        ...     
        end
    end
end
```

I get this:

[stack overflow doesn't let me post pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVdH1.png)

Since I don't want the extra "<" and ">", what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: As extra information, on my view I am just doing:

```
<%= user_log %>
```

Comment: Also, why do you need a span class around your input tags? Why not just put the class definition on the input tag itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that you are using content_tag twice when you don't need to. [content_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag) essentially calls [content_tag_string](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TagHelper/content_tag_string). Here's `content_tag_string`'s source:

```
def content_tag_string(name, content, options, escape = true)
  tag_options = tag_options(options, escape) if options
  "<#{name}#{tag_options}>#{content}</#{name}>".html_safe
end
```

Calling `content_tag(text_field_tag :email, "email@domain.com")` looks like:

```
"<#{text_field_tag :email, "email@domain.com"}>"
```

and text_field_tag already produces a full HTML tag (it includes the "<" and ">").

All you need to do to get rid of the extra angled brackets is to leave out the second `content_tag`:

```
content_tag(:span, text_field_tag(:email, "email@domain.com"), :class => "memail")+
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much, solved it AND I understood what was happening

Answer (score 0):

As a first guess, I might try something like:

```
if logged_in? == false
  ...
else
  ...
end.html_safe
```

*Update:* Ok, back to the drawing board.

As a second guess, try this. (And note the extra parameter to `content_tag`, which required putting the hash in explicit { }...)

```
def user_log
    if logged_in? == false
        form_tag session_path, :id => "mform" do
          (
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(text_field_tag :email, "email@domain.com"),   {:class => "memail"},   false)+
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(password_field_tag :password, "12345678912"), {:class => "mpass"},    false)+
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(submit_tag 'Login'),                          {:class => "mbutton"},  false)
          ).html_safe
        end
    else
        ...     
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Gah tried the updated version, and to no avail. Keep getting the same result. Instead of making this approach work, is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Well, be sure you tried the latest version. It says I edited it *x* minutes ago, but it's actually less because it doesn't count closely following edits. Anyway, I've had similar problems with content_tag, you might just try generating the <span> blocks by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tried it locally, the problem is likely that Rails is html escaping your handy helper method. To see if I'm right, try throwing this in your view:

```
<%= raw(user_log) %>
```

If that works, you can throw `raw` in your helper method instead:

```
def user_log
    if logged_in? == false
        raw(form_tag session_path, :id => "mform" do
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(text_field_tag :email, "email@domain.com"), :class => "memail")+
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(password_field_tag :password, "12345678912"), :class => "mpass")+
            content_tag(:span, content_tag(submit_tag 'Login'), :class => "mbutton")
        end)
    else
        ...     
    end
end
```

`raw` tells Rails that this code is safe and doesn't need to be html escaped.

Comment: The first raw(use_log) option, does nothing different from what I have now. The second throws a bunch of exceptions...