# Ruby on rails html displaying extra characters

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-3.1

below is the html code that i wrote for my view

```
display_command_list.html.erb

<div id="List of commands">
<a href="http://localhost:3000/authorization/check_validity">Click here to make a deployment group </a>
<a href="#"> Relational Conncetions</a>
<a href="#"> To see the workflows that are running</a>
</div>
```

And here is what printed on my view

```
<Click here to make a deployment group < Relational Conncetions< To see the workflows that are running<
```

I could not understand where these extra '<' are coming from. This seems strange to me. Please let me know who to get rid of them if you came across something like this before

Update: They are not appearing when i created an entierly new application

Comment: Weird... It seems to render correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/HZfnq/ -- Can you write the complete html.erb file?

Comment: Maybe your problem is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4776594/rails-content-tag-inserts-extra-and-characters .

Comment: @afaf12 He is using variable from his method in the view. Im not using anything from my method. I just wrote plain html in the view.html.erb where no variable or tag or anything from the controller is used. To test, i deleted the content in html.erb file and the view has no extra tags '<' and is blank